# sql query to compare two fields of the table

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables: table1 with field id and table2 with filed prv_id

Eg: table1:    id

```
         06G35ME
         03G66UN
```

table2:  prv_id

```
        456P1BU-06G35ME
        06G35ME
        72006G35ME
        4D022HO-06G35ME
        06G35ME-06G35ME
        07R63EV-06G35ME
        06G36EV-06G35ME
        247S4HO-06G35ME
        MNG06G35ME
```

so i have to find all prv_id which are like id. I am using LIKE command to compare the fields but i am not getting any output. Please help

Comment: Your tags don't make any sense. Please pick one or the other.

Comment: Seeing your query would be useful.

Comment: Please also give us the query you made

Comment: Are you forgetting to include the preceding wildcard character? In T-Sql it's `%`, but I don't know about MySQL.

Comment: i am using below query : select a.prv_id from table1 a left join table2 b on a.prv_id = b.id where a.prv_id like '%b.id%'

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this will work in SQL Server and MySQL

```
select a.prv_id 
from table1 a 
left join table2 b 
   on a.prv_id like '%'+b.id+'%'
```